# How can I have the Physical path by giving the network path

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Well now i have an issue which is pointing in the use of "path's" physical and network.
I have a SQL server on a Server machine and i have a desktop machine used as client.
I'm runing from my client machine a stored procedure in order to add a streaming data base.
But also before i run this procedure i run another one which prepare the desired "path", this procedure takes:

```
myPath="\\Server\SharedFolder\SQL\
```

in order to run the first procedure i have to turn myPath in each physical name:

```
myPath="DriveLetter:\Public\WorkFiles\SQL\"
```

Now my Issue is how i will have the physical path, which is build it on the server and which it's from very difficult (to imposible) to know it? 
Basically i need a function which will return me the physical path, which the implementation it's not knowing to me. My developing environment is vb.net 2010
Is there anyone to assist me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [NetShareEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525387%28VS.85%29.aspx) Windows API for this, passing the server's name as the first parameter, with level 2 or 502. Then you can do a match based on the returned paths.

Of course, you will need special group membership for this (Administrator, Power User, Print Operator, or Server Operator) kind of call to succeed.

Comment: Well Dear Simon, of course i will thank you very much for your answer, and i will admit that i spend alot of time with your proposal, but i haven't conclude anywhere. I use the Public Declare Function NetShareGetInfo Lib "Netapi32.dll" (ByVal strServerName As Object, ByVal strNetName As Object, ByVal nLevel As Long, ByVal pBuffer As Long) As Long . But i take the following error :

Comment: Continuing:= PInvokeStackImbalance was detected
Message: A call to PInvoke function 'AssetsManagement!AssetsManagement.Common_Proc::NetShareGetInfo' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.
I use the vb.net developing environment so please is there any workable solution?

Comment: Hi, I'm not familiar with VB.NET syntax, but the p/invoke declaration here does not look good, have a look at this link: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32.netsharegetinfo

Comment: Dear Simon YOU ARE THE ONLY BEST thank you very very much. the all issue is working exactly as i was expected. It is the true that the code is huge and hard. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
    Dim foo As String = "\\DLINK_NAS\Volume_1"
    Dim dirInfo As New IO.DirectoryInfo(foo)

    For Each drv As IO.DriveInfo In My.Computer.FileSystem.Drives
        If drv.IsReady AndAlso dirInfo.Name = drv.VolumeLabel Then
            'match here
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Dear dbasnett, thank you very much for your answer but that is not what i want to have. Because you see i want to have the physical dimentions of the Network drive "\\ServerName\SharedName\instalation_path" you see the only item i have is the name of the server and the shared path, and with these two parameters i have make all of my job.